# When was the last Canon EF lens with Arc-Form Drive produced?

Tags: canon-ef

The first Canon EF lenses for EOS cameras were first produced in 1987 and 1988 when Canon first started the new EOS system.

Some EF Arc-Form Drive lenses like the EF 35mm f/2 and EF 50mm f/2.5 Macro were in continuous production during this time.

They were all produced in the same Utsunomiya, Japan factory and always included a date code stamped on the lens.

More recent Arc Form Drive lens production included the 24mm f/2.8, 28mm f/2.8, 35mm f/2, 50mm f/2.5, and 135mm f/2.8SF

Does anyone know when the last of these Arc-Form Drive lenses was produced?

EF 35mm f/2 lens with 2008 date code

[image]

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: No problem,  just a curiosity.  I am somewhat of a colector of old Canon EF lenses and would like to know which EF lens had the longest production run.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I don't think that Canon has continuous lens production as such. I believe they are built in batches, then stored and sold over time, and a new batch produced if and when needed, until the lens is finally discontinued. If so, this makes it hard to say when the "last" AFD lens was produced, as you never know if they are going to make another batch of one next week. Unless you know that all AFD lenses are officially discontinued, of course.

Comment: I do belive that all these AFD lenses have been discontinued as they show discontinued on various retailer websites

Comment: Some of the more popular lenses seem to have examples from pretty much every month (which is as specific as the date code gets). But in general you are correct, most lenses are made in batches and stockpiled until more are needed. At the end of their life as a "current" lens many lenses may not have been made for several years until the current inventory is depleted or a replacement is announced.